# SQL Replace function will not be working in my case

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, replace

I have a question regarding to Replace function:

MyTable:

```
ID     | Header| Year
-----------------------
123    |   1   | 2017
456    |   3   | 2016
658    |   2   | 2015
587    |   6   | 2014
....
```

I want to replace the income codes with the real values like:

- If 1 it will be $31230-$41400
- If 2 it will be $41560-$50300
- If 3 it will be $51620-$60200
- If 4 it will be $61230-$73000
- If 9....

I could not use the Replace function in this case,

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    REPLACE (REPLACE(INCOME_CODE, '1','$31230-$41400'), '2', '$41560-$50300'), 
    YEAR 
FROM 
    MyTable
```

Because the second REPLACE function will grasp any number 2 in the first replacement and replace with $41560-$50300.

It would be came something like
$31$41560-$5030030-$41400.

Comment: What database are you using? mysql and SQL Server are 2 different databases.

Comment: There is 99.9999% chance that you have in your database a dimension table that  holds the information of the codes, and if there isn't - create one.

Comment: Good point, the best solution (if possible) would be to join to the income codes table and get the values from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` statement.

```
CASE INCOME_CODE
     WHEN 1 THEN '$31230-$41400'
     WHEN 2 THEN '$41560-$50300'
     WHEN 3 THEN '$$51620-$60200'
     WHEN 4 THEN '$61230-$73000'
     ..
END
```

Comment: Sorry might be silly question (I use DB2), is WHEN not mandatory is mysql?

Comment: It is mandatory. In this case since I specify INCOME_CODE at the beginning of my `CASE` statement, I can just use simple `WHEN` comparisons in the rest of my statement.

Comment: In this way you don't have to put `WHEN INCOME_CODE =` for each of your WHEN clauses.

Comment: It is working out perfect for me, thank you so much! You have saved my day! David

Answer (score 0):

You need to use case statement

```
 SELECT ID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN INCOME_CODE = '1'
            THEN '$31230-$41400' )
        WHEN INCOME_CODE = '2'
            THEN '$41560-$50300'
        END AS income
    ,YEAR
FROM MyTable
```